# How to substract values of same keys of two defaultdicts of ints

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict, dictionary-comprehension

I have two defaultdicts with different values (and possibly keys). I want to create a third one with the result of the substraction of the same keyed values. I know it is easy but I cannot find a pythonic way to do it (not a for loop).

I suppose I should use operator.sub and some combination of map.

```
a = defaultdict(int)
b = defaultdict(int)

a['8'] += 500
a['9'] += 400
b['8'] += 300
```

I would expect:

```
c 
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'8': 200, '9': 400 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`

**Ex:**

```
a = defaultdict(int)
b = defaultdict(int)

a['8'] += 500
a['9'] += 400
b['8'] += 300
print(Counter(a) - Counter(b))
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'9': 400, '8': 200})
```